# Is there any way to remove the listener without its name or remove all listener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As the title, is there any way to remove all listeners without it's name or some thing like that?

This is what I am doing:

```
ref.removeEventListener(valueEventName);
```

Comment: why did my question is marked duplicate ? please read the question carefully, I dont ask about how to remove. I want to know if there is a way to remove Listener without its name.

Comment: Hey Tran. To remove an event listener from a query, you must have a reference to the listener. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen , I already knew that. I just confuse a little bit about remove Listener without its name. But I think it is not posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to remove a listener from a query/location in Android, you need to have a reference to that listener. See the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)).

There is no method in the Android SDK to remove all listeners from a query/location.